# SQL find different time based on two tables using a third table as a key on MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am learning to use MySQL query inside a Python project.

I am using MySQLDB module in Python to upload and data to my MySQL database and now, I want to compare data and print out the difference.

I have 3 tables(only included relevant columns):

## name

- rawid
- origid
- name

## rawdata

- rawid
- date
- total

## origdata

- origid
- date
- total

I need to compare 'total' of the same person depending on the date.

e.g. From 2020-05-02 to 2020-05-09, I want to print origid, rawid, name, date, and total if the origdata total and rawdata total does not match for the matching date and person.

What is the query I can compare and return relevant information?

What I want to accomplish is something similar to the following:

```
SELECT n.name
     , o.date
     , o.total
     , r.total raw_total
  FROM origdata o
  LEFT 
  JOIN name n
    ON n.origid = o.origId 
  LEFT 
  JOIN rawdata r 
    ON r.rawId = n.rawId
 WHERE o.date >= '2020-05-02' 
   AND o.date < '2020-05-10'
 GROUP 
    BY o.origId
     , o.date
```

When this is ran, `rawdata`.`total` does not show correct values; value of `origdata`.`total` and `rawdata`.`total` should be the same.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I have added more information and the way I want to approach but I don't know how much of a help this is. Please let me know if there is more information I should add for a better communication.

Comment: Also, be aware that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If your "date" column is DATETIME type, you could use CAST:

```
 SELECT n.name
        , o.date
        , o.total
        , r.total raw_total
    FROM origdata o
    LEFT 
    JOIN name n
        ON n.origid = o.origId 
    LEFT 
    JOIN rawdata r 
        ON r.rawId = n.rawId
    WHERE CAST(o.date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2020-05-02' AND '2020-05-10'
    GROUP 
        BY o.origId
        , o.date
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have records in the same table with the same date, first you need to aggregate them (Group By - Sum)

```
SELECT n.name, o.date, 
o.total as orig_total, 
r.total as raw_total

FROM
(
    select o.origid, o.date, sum(o.total) as total
    from origdata o
    group by o.origid, o.date
) o
JOIN 
(
    select r.rawid, r.date, sum(r.total) as total
    from rawdata r
    group by r.rawid, r.date
) r
on o.origid = r.rawid 
and o.date = r.date
LEFT JOIN name n
on o.origid = n.origid
and r.rawid = n.rawid

WHERE  o.date >= '2020-05-02' 
and o.date < '2020-05-10'
and not o.total = r.total
```

Consider that this will only return coincident dates in both tables. If you want to include null date values, you need to use a LEFT AND RIGHT JOIN, because MySql does not support OUTER JOINS

```
SELECT n.name, o.date, 
o.total as orig_total, 
r.total as raw_total
FROM (
    select o.origid, o.date, sum(o.total) as total
    from origdata o
    group by o.origid, o.date
) o
LEFT JOIN (
    select r.rawid, r.date, sum(r.total) as total
    from rawdata r
    group by r.rawid, r.date
) r
on o.origid = r.rawid 
and o.date = r.date
LEFT JOIN name n
on o.origid = n.origid
and r.rawid = n.rawid

WHERE r.rawid is null
and  o.date >= '2020-05-02' 
and o.date < '2020-05-10'

UNION

SELECT n.name, r.date, 
o.total as orig_total, 
r.total as raw_total
FROM (
    select o.origid, o.date, sum(o.total) as total
    from origdata o
    group by o.origid, o.date
) o
RIGHT JOIN (
    select r.rawid, r.date, sum(r.total) as total
    from rawdata r
    group by r.rawid, r.date
) r
on o.origid = r.rawid 
and o.date = r.date
LEFT JOIN name n
on o.origid = n.origid
and r.rawid = n.rawid

WHERE o.origid is null
and  r.date >= '2020-05-02' 
and r.date < '2020-05-10'
```

NOTE: one way to do it would be using CTE, but prior to version 8, MySql does not support that. then I tried using temporary tables to make it easier, but apparently the same temp_table cannot be read twice in the same statement, giving me a Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table 'o'  (I'm using MySql 5.7)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_origdata AS 
(
select o.origid, o.date, sum(o.total) as total
from origdata o
group by o.origid, o.date
)

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_rawdata AS 
(
select r.rawid, r.date, sum(r.total) as total
from rawdata r
group by r.rawid, r.date
)    

SELECT n.name, o.date, 
o.total as orig_total, 
r.total as raw_total
from temp_origdata o
left join temp_rawdata r
on o.origid = r.rawid 
and o.date = r.date
LEFT JOIN name n
on o.origid = n.origid
and r.rawid = n.rawid
where r.rawid is null
and  o.date >= '2020-05-02' 
and o.date < '2020-05-10'

union

SELECT n.name, o.date, 
o.total as orig_total, 
r.total as raw_total
from temp_origdata o
right join temp_rawdata r
on o.origid = r.rawid 
and o.date = r.date
LEFT JOIN name n
on o.origid = n.origid
and r.rawid = n.rawid
where o.origid is null
and  r.date >= '2020-05-02' 
and r.date < '2020-05-10'
```